# cover page--"The" is separated from "Publisher"--also how to put a clean page break to stop raggedleft on second page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}                 %inter office note /cover page vertical line template
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                      %for color of table
\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{multirow}           % Required for multirows
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}             % Generic dummy publisher logo 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}             %best

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%%\raggedleft
                                        % Right align the title page
    \rule{1pt}{\textheight}              % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth}              % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.6\textwidth}
    {                        % Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move                                  the title page left or right on the page        
        {\Huge
            \bfseries 
            Key Result Areas \\
            [0.5\baselineskip] 
            August 2019}\\
            [2\baselineskip] % Title
        \begin{itemize}
        \item {\large
                \textit
                { DGQA Unit Run Canteen\\ 
        \item ISO Certification 9001:2015\\
        \item CQA(AVL) Standing Orders}}
        \\[4\baselineskip] % Subtitle or further description
        \end{itemize}
        {\Large
            \textsc
            {colonel js bibra\\
                joint controller}
            } % Author name, lower case for consistent small caps
        \vspace
            {0.45\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
        {\noindent 
            The Publisher~~\plogo}\\
        [\baselineskip] % Publisher and logo
    }
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the "The publisher": An empty line before `{\noindent 
            The Publisher` should help.

Comment: Regarding the `\raggedright` alignment: `\begingroup\raggedright` and `\newpage\endgroup` should work.

Comment: I would also use the following code for the list: `\begin{itemize}\large\itshape
        \item DGQA Unit Run Canteen`. Currently there is an extra space before the first item and teh bullet point of the first item has a slightly different size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\vspace` doesn't end a paragraph.

I would use different coding, easier and clearer.

For instance, you can set a `minipage` (or `\parbox`) with a predetermined height, so you don't need to guess the spacing before the publisher. Better a `minipage`, so its beginning and end are more prominent in the code.

Paragraphs should be ended before the end of a size changing scope. Also you have more control on the size if you use `\MakeUppercase` to ensure uppercasing, rather than relying on small caps.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}                 %inter office note /cover page vertical line template
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}          % Generic dummy publisher logo 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}             % best

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

% Vertical line
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}% <--- don't forget
% Some space after it
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}% <--- don'f forget
% Paragraph box for holding the title page text,
\begin{minipage}[b][\textheight][s]{0.6\textwidth}
  \raggedright

  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

  {\Huge\bfseries 
   Key Result Areas \\
   August 2019\\}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}

  {\large
   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
   \item \textit{DGQA Unit Run Canteen}

   \item ISO Certification 9001:2015

   \item CQA(AVL) Standing Orders
   \end{itemize}}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}

  \MakeUppercase{Colonel JS Bibra}\\
  \MakeUppercase{Joint Controller}

  \vfill

  The Publisher~~\plogo

  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

  \end{minipage}

\end{flushleft}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

With an image on the left of the rule, vertically centered with respect to the rule:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}}          % Generic dummy publisher logo 
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}             % best

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

% Logo on the left side
\begin{minipage}[b][\textheight][s]{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{example-image}}

\vspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}%
% Vertical line with some space on either side
\quad
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}% <--- don't forget
\quad
% Paragraph box for holding the title page text,
\begin{minipage}[b][\textheight][s]{0.6\textwidth}
  \raggedright

  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

  {\Huge\bfseries 
   Key Result Areas \\
   August 2019\\}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}

  {\large
   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
   \item \textit{DGQA Unit Run Canteen}

   \item ISO Certification 9001:2015

   \item CQA(AVL) Standing Orders
   \end{itemize}}

  \vspace{2\baselineskip}

  \MakeUppercase{Colonel JS Bibra}\\
  \MakeUppercase{Joint Controller}

  \vfill

  The Publisher~~\plogo

  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}

  \end{minipage}

\end{flushleft}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @egreg--also let me know how to adjust the spacing between lpm and the vertical line--i want put a logo between the left page margin-lpm- and the vertical line -the logo centred between top and bottom of page-- and logo will have  border around it

Comment: how to adjust the spacing between left page margin and the vertical line--i want to put a logo between the left page margin-lpm- and the vertical line -the logo centred between top and bottom of page-- and logo will have border around it

Comment: @jsbibra Use the same idea, I added a possible solution.